# How to validate dynamic controls in .net core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am creating the survey application for which I am creating the controls dynamically(Like checkbox,radio-button,textbox etc).

Each question will have the controls depending upon the control type assigned to the question and on question type the answer choices(checkbox, radio button) will be rendered.

On Next/Previous navigation I am storing current page answers in the database. While navigating the page I am doing ajax call for database saving and my UI/controls are NOT in the form.

I have created ViewModel based on my LMS_SurveyQuestions and LMS_SurveyQuestionOptionChoice table.

So, while creating the UI in view in for loop, I have directly assigned  `SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceID` as Control ID while creating the AnswerChoice controls and stored the same in the table SurveyUserAnswer table.

Model

```
 public class LMS_TraineeSurveyPaginationViewModel
 {
     public List<LMS_SurveyQuestions> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
     public List<LMS_SurveyQuestionOptionChoice> SurveyQuestionOptionChoice { get; set; }
     public SurveyPager Pager { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is how I rendered the view

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SurveyQuestions)
{
    foreach (var data in Model.SurveyQuestionOptionChoice.Where(x => x.SurveyQuestionID == item.SurveyQuestionID).ToList())
    {
        if (item.QuestionTypeID == QuestionType.RadioButton)
        {
            <li style="list-style:none;">
            <input type="radio" name="rb" id="@data.SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceID"  />
            <span>@data.OptionChoice</span>
            </li>
        }
        else if (item.QuestionTypeID == QuestionType.CheckBox)
        {
            <li style="list-style:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="@data.SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceID" name="@data.SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceID" " />
            <span>@data.OptionChoice</span>
            </li>
        }
    }
}
```

and while saving the answer into database I have created the JSON/JS array as model for SurveyUserAnswer and saved it into database as follows. Below is example for radio button

```
function SaveValues() {
    var surveyQuestion = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.SurveyQuestions.ToArray()));
    var surveyQuestionOptionChoide = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.SurveyQuestionOptionChoice.ToArray()));
    for (item in surveyQuestion) {
        var surveyQuestionID=surveyQuestionViewModel[item].SurveyQuestionID;
        var filteredData = surveyQuestionOptionChoide.filter(function(filteredItem) {
            return (filteredItem.SurveyQuestionID==surveyQuestionID);
        });
        for (optionChoice in filteredData) {
            if(surveyQuestion[item].QuestionTypeID=='@QuestionType.RadioButton') {
                if (($('#'+SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceID).prop("checked"))) {
                    surveyUserAnswer.push({ SurveyUserAnswerID: filteredData[optionChoice].SurveyUserAnswerID==null?0:filteredData[optionChoice].SurveyUserAnswerID,
                    SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceID: SurveyQuestionOptionChoiceID,SurveyUserID:'@ViewBag.SurveyUserID',AnswerText:null,
                    MarksObtained:filteredData[optionChoice].Marks,WhenCreated:'@DateTime.UtcNow',WhoCreated:'@tenant.UserID'});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $.post('@Url.Action("GetTraineeSurvey", "Survey")', {SurveyID:surveyID,page:page, surveyUserAnswer: surveyUserAnswer,PrevBranchQuestionPage:currentPage,IsBranchQuestionAvailable:IsBranchQuestionAvailable }, function (data) {
        $('#surveyModalContent').html('');
        $('#surveyModalContent').html(data);
        $("#surveyModal").modal('show');
    }).fail(function() {
        alert( "error in GetTraineeSurvey" );
    }).success(function() { });
}
```

So, my question is how can I validate dynamically created controls in this scenario ?

Comment: @ Dawid Rutkowski  Thanks for the edit. Any solution on my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unobtrusive jQuery validation basic on data attributes on controls.
Read more about that on this [LINK](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html).

Comment: yeah but I cannot add required attribute on model property,  as sometimes validation will not be required.  So if validation is required then it should get added to the control else not

Comment: You can add data-required attribute on your dynamically added input, like is described on link.

Comment: No that's not working ! My controls are on bootstrap modal, is that a problem ?